# How do I get firefox do use the numix theme again?

Tags: firefox, themes, kde, numix

I normally use Ubuntu 15.10 with the numix theme, the typical black style with red menus along with circle icons. I recently tried kde plasma(because for whatever reason it was installed on my system), and I think it disrupted the theme files because now my firefox is using a kde theme with blue menus and off white. How do I get my firefox to use numix again?

Comment: Let me mention that I reverted back to Unity desktop, and firefox is the only program where this issue is happening. Oddly enough, I can launch it with the proper numix theme installed by running env GTK2_RC_FILES= firefox in terminal.

Comment: ACTUALLY, I'm getting blue menus everywhere in applications where it's not in the menu bar or in nautilus.

Comment: It's not advisable to mix-n-match desktop environments. Removing traces of KDE is particularly troublesome. When 16.04 is released do a clean install of whatever flavor of Ubuntu you want. Don't add more desktop environments. If you really want to try some, use VirtualBox.

Comment: If only I knew that beforehand, I just recently got back into linux so I've trying new things. So is there really no way to fix this in the mean time? When I clean install, should wipe partition and install from a USB drive?